# java spring H2 merge sql syntax error

Tags: sql, spring, h2

I cant figure out what is wrong with this merge statement.  It was working fine then I added COL2 in the statement, following the same pattern I believed but I get this error which seems to indicate it comes from aliasing the table?

> ```
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement 
> "MERGE INTO MY_TABLE RBX[*] USING ( SELECT ? COL1,? COL2,? COL3,? COL4, 
> ? COL5, ? COL6,? UPDATED_TS FROM DUAL) R ON (RBX.COL1 = R.COL1 AND 
> RBX.COL5 = R.COL5) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET RBX.COL3 = R.COL3, 
> RBX.COL4 = R.COL4,  RBX.COL6 = R.COL6, RBX.COL2 = R.COL2, 
> RBX.UPDATED_TS = R.UPDATED_TS WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(COL1, COL2, 
> COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, UPDATED_TS) VALUES(R.COL1, R.COL2, R.COL3, 
> R.COL4, R.COL5, R.COL6, R.UPDATED_TS)";expected "., (, KEY, VALUES, (, 
> WITH, SELECT, FROM";SQL statement:
> ```

The statement is:

```
MERGE INTO MY_TABLE RBX 
USING ( SELECT ? COL1,? COL2,? COL3,? COL4, ? COL5, ? COL6,? UPDATED_TS 
FROM DUAL) R 
ON (RBX.COL1 = R.COL1 AND RBX.COL5 = R.COL5) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET RBX.COL3 = R.COL3, RBX.COL4 = R.COL4,  RBX.COL6 = R.COL6, 
RBX.COL2 = R.COL2, 
RBX.UPDATED_TS = R.UPDATED_TS 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, UPDATED_TS) VALUES(R.COL1, 
R.COL2, R.COL3, R.COL4, R.COL5, R.COL6, R.UPDATED_TS) [42001-196]
```

I am prone to random blindness but this statement looks correct to me.  Is it possible the error could be a result of something else?  Table set up, etc?

In particular, can someone explain what this means:

```
";expected "., (, KEY, VALUES, (, WITH, SELECT, FROM";
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Even if I run the example [from the manual](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge_using) I get that error.

Comment: indeed it appears to be a bug.  i hooked up to our test env and the query worked as expected.  thank you @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on H2 while the request works find on DB2. @futevolei did you find any workaround on H2 ?

Comment: Our solution, unfortunately, was to create a different sql statement for our h2 db test cases than the one we use in prod...